# Ubuntu 16.04: Truffle: command not found

Tags: truffle, ubuntu, installation

I installed the truffle on my Ubuntu machine and it installed successfully but when i am trying to execute truffle commands it is saying;
truffle: command not found

I tried the solution mentioned in this question
[Unable to install Truffle - Command Not Found](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42805/unable-to-install-truffle-command-not-found)

but it didn't worked for me.
I think the environment variable path is not set or there is some issue in node modules.

Please give a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install it with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, i did. I tried to uninstall and install, i did this more than 2-3 times, but no luck. Every time it is installed successfully and when i tried to check its version by truffle -v it is showing this error. Command not found